# Open Tab on page load in magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, tabs

I have code like below in my html file

```
  <div class="payment-option _collapsible opc-payment-additional discount-code"
     data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}">
    <div class="payment-option-title field choice" data-role="title">
        <span class="action action-toggle" id="block-comment-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
            <!-- ko i18n: 'Customer Note'--><!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-option-content" data-role="content">
        <form class="form form-discount" id="comment-form">
            <div class="payment-option-inner">
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label" for="comment-code">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Enter your comment'"></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea class="input-text" id="comment-code" name="comment-code" rows="2" maxlength="200" data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Enter comment')} " ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which opens tab on clicking the Customer Note text, how to open the tab on page load itself. please anybody suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `active` to true:

Change

```
data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': '_active'}}">
```

To

```
data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{active: true, 'openedState': '_active'}}">
```

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_collapsible.html for more options.

Answer (score 3):

You can open this tab on page load itself by below script:

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).on("load", function () {
        jQuery("#Tab").fadeIn();
    });
</script>
```